# Adding unique xticks for subplots with shared x-axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to generate 3 plots similar to this
[image: img]

Each plot basically represents a sound signal. Now I have shared the `x axis` for all subplots. What I can not seem to achieve is **How do I add the `xticks` for each subplot and still keep the axes shared?**

Here is my code:

```py
def set_ax(ax,x,y,ticks,label,color):
    """
        Set the axes object for each subplot
    """
    ax.step(x, y, color=color, label=label)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.2,0.7)
    ax.set_xticklabels(list(map(str,ticks)), rotation=45,ha='right')
    ax.set_yticks([0,0.5],minor=False)
    ax.legend()

def plot_comparison(rt, pt, ep):
    """ 
        Plot the following rt, pt and ep for comparision 
    """
    rx,ry,rt = get_coords(rt) # returns tuple of 3 numpy arrays (x,y,ticks) for rt
    px,py,pt = get_coords(pt) # returns tuple of 3 numpy arrays (x,y,ticks) for pt
    ex,ey,et = get_coords(ep) # returns tuple of 3 numpy arrays (x,y,ticks) for ep

    fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, constrained_layout=True, sharex=True)

    set_ax(ax1, rx, ry, rt, 'Raw truth',       'green')
    set_ax(ax2, px, py, pt, 'Processed truth', 'darkorange')
    set_ax(ax3, ex, ey, et, 'EP output',       'red')

    plt.show()
```

I set the `xticks` for each of `ax1`, `ax2` and `ax3` in the `set_ax()` calls inside `plot_comparison()` function but they all seem to be overwritten by the ticks of `ax3`. I want to keep everything in the figure above and just add the `xticks` to the first(green) and second(gold) plots. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So, do you want the gridlines and tick positions for each individual plot? And each with its own labels? Just leave out the sharing of x. And maually set the ax.xlim of each axis to the same value.

Comment: I want the grid lines to be as it is. I essentially want to compare the red curve to the the other 2 curves and wanted to add tick labels to the yellow and green curves